# Can a brine water electrolysis be looped?

Tags: aqueous-solution, electrolysis

Electrolysis of brine yields hydrogen and chlorine gases and aqueous $\ce{NaOH}$. So is it possible to combine the gases to form $\ce{HCl}$ gas, and mix it back with the aqueous $\ce{NaOH}$, so it returns to brine water?

Comment: Of course. But the reaction of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ would be explosive. The combination is often called *Chlorknallgas* — chlorine explosive gas — in German.

Comment: Yes I have seen the individual reactions on Youtube, but I just never saw anyone loop the whole process.

Comment: I have to know, is this the start of the most ill advised perpetual motion/over unity machine attempt ever?

Comment: No, I never thought that this can be an over unity machine from the start. This may be of other uses though.

Comment: Well there would be no *reason* to loop the process other than demonstrate that it's possible …

Comment: there are actually very good rea sons to loop this process. if you can use these salts to store and transport hydrogen this could be an important component in a renewable energy system.